# Laravel 5 not creating logs

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting started with Laravel 5, using Homestead/Vagrant for a server, SSHing in with Putty.

I'm building my first site and it's not creating a log in `/storage/logs`. Neither is it displaying errors. I've run `chmod -777` on the `/storage` directory, so that's not it. Any ideas?

UPDATE: as suggested, I went into the error.log in vagrant/var/hhvm/. Sure enough, that was it. The error was "\nFatal error: `Class undefined: HTML in /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/storage/framework/views/441aef21be6c3c32079f86e5812a9d0a on line 39"`.

I followed the steps listed below to add the class. http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation Edited the composer.json, ran composer update, added the provider and aliases. Still getting the white screen of death.

There is now a log in `/storage/`, which says:

```
[2015-05-27 11:33:44] local.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command "tail" is not defined.' in /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:549 , followed by a stack trace. This seems to be the error thrown by my attempt to run laravel tail, which I did before looking in the vagrant log. Nothing in there about why it's not loading now.
```

Comment: Try running `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: Check `/var/log/hhvm/error.log` in the Vagrant box. Some fatal errors go there before Laravel gets a chance to catch them.

Comment: OK, some progress. Edited question. Thanks for continuing your help, guys, I feel like there is some minor thing jacking this all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [FBidu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2713733/fbidu) answered very good answer,but `artisan tail` is not come with default package in laravel 5. However can be installed with
`composer require spatie/laravel-tail`

In config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    'Spatie\Tail\TailServiceProvider',
    ...
];
```

After that’s done you can tail your local log with

`php artisan tail`

The remote log can be tailed with
`php artisan tail production`

[Link here](https://murze.be/2015/02/the-missing-tail-command-for-laravel-5/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to do an `chmod -R 777` on storage to guarantee that all of the files and folders within storage are writeable.

Secondly, it would be nice to allow the debug mode!

You can also try to run `artisan tail` to get the latest logs